# how to add cron job from ssh root ( httpd , mysql )

Tags: ssh, root

i need to make my vps restart httpd apache and mysql every day

my /etc/crontab file records is

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
29 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
43 0 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
13 5 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
23 0 28 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

if i want to make httpd and mysql restart every day what i have to add in this file and where !

aim still newer in this staff

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to restart these 2 services everyday?

Comment: my server used for shared hosting i want to restart them to clean cache for each service every day , so please what lines i have to add

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add anything to that file.

Create a script to restart the services, and put it in the `/etc/cron.daily/` directory.

Comment: i duono how to create a script for that , any advice !

Comment: A shell script is just a file containing the commands you would type. If you don't know how to do that, you're in the wrong job.